# how do i calculate the maximum serialized integers in 1024 length limit

Tags: integer

I'm allowed to have a maximum length of `1024`, How far can i go in serialized integers 
in this cell from `0 to ?` as `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 . . . .`

for example if maximum length is `5`
my maximum number i can reach is **4** `0 1 2 3 **4**` and if maximum length is `12` my maximum number would be **10** `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 **10**`

Comment: What's a serialized integer?  And the maximum size that an unsigned integer can be is 2^32 (signed is 2^31 - 1)

Comment: @JacobG.i mean serialized as `1 2 3 4 5 ...`, And yes UNSIGNED, So 2^32 is the maximum number i can reach? And may i ask how did we calculate that?

Comment: Yes, but what does the maximum length of 1024 refer to?

Comment: @JacobG Updated the question to clear that

Comment: Your second example doesn't make sense.  If your maximum length is 12, why is 10 the maximum integer?  Shouldn't it be 11?

Comment: @JacobG. because the letters count without the spaces is `12`, Or does 12 count as 1 letter in some languages?

Comment: In hexadecimal it would count as one character ;) but I understand now, I'll write a program that can solve this for you and post it as an answer.

Comment: @JacobG.If that would be easier, You can just type the mathematical formula.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not really a mathematical formula, but there might be a way to do it mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program in Java that solves this problem:

```
private static final int MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 1_024;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(MAXIMUM_LENGTH);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; sb.length() < MAXIMUM_LENGTH; i++) {
        sb.append(i);
    }

    System.out.println(i - 1);
}
```

Maximum Length | Maximum Integer

```
   5 | 4
  12 | 10
1024 | 377
```

How it works: It appends every ascending `int` to a `String`, and constantly checks its length to see if it is greater than or equal to the maximum length.  If it is, then it grabs the previous integer (the answer).

Comment: so here the maxlength of `1024` can accept nubmers up to `377` only, you made an awesome program here.

Comment: Yep!  And thank you, this would be an excellent question for code golf!